# Uploading an Existing Maven Eclipse Project into GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github

There are several examples on StackOverflow and on the web for creating a repository on GitHub and dowloading the repository into Eclipse.  Most of these examples are very basic and very old.

I am looking for an up to date and clear step by step example that shows how to **upload an existing Maven project** from Eclipse to GitHub.  The instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/423792/how-to-push-an-existing-eclipse-project-to-github) fail every time.

I thought this would be really easy to do.  It has been two hours of frustration.  Is there a more elegant solution out there than GitHub?

Comment: Does this not help? https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github And what does "fail every time" mean? What errors do you get? What is not working as expected?

Comment: I would like to be able to use the GitHub capabilities through the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Which step exactly does it fail at? Describe as precisely as possible and name the error message you get. Screenshots might be helpful. Have you tried right-clicking the project and choosing _Team > Share Project_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the instructions found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/423792/how-to-push-an-existing-eclipse-project-to-github) that kept failing for me.

1. Go to github create new empty repository
2. Copy the https URL from github
3. Go to Eclipse --> Right click on project --> Team--> share project-->
4. Create new Git Repo.
5. Go to Git Staging--> Stage all changes --> "Commit" (do not "Commit and Push")
6. Right click on your Git Repository, select "Push Branch Master"
7. Paste your https URL of githun which you copy in step 2

Answer (score 1):

I would just handle it as it was a normal folder you want to push to GitHub.

So what you basically do is just what Github says if you create a new repo:

Navigate the bash into your folder, then...

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin YOUR_GIT_REPO_LINK
git push -u origin master
```

I think this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I would like to be able to use the GitHub capabilities through the Eclipse IDE.